# one tap wifi widget similar to power control widget?

Tags: app-widgets

I recently bought a new phone and was surprised that the power control widget is no longer a thing. I tried many other widget and they're either just shortcuts to the settings or they straight up don't work. Do you know a similar widget to activate wifi/ data/ bluetooth in just one tap?

Comment: Looks like your old phone was really old. If I remember correctly those widgets disappeared because Google removed the possibility to enable/disable those settings by apps and windgets in newer Android versions (without root). Also there is now the swipe from top menu which contains all the necessary switches.

Comment: Ok, so it's impossible? That widget was simply brilliant and brilliantly simple.